# Combining squats and deadlifts: do deadlifts on light or heavy squat day?

Tags: squats, recovery, deadlifts, programming

Currently I'm doing 3 workouts per week: Monday, Wednseday, Friday. There's two workout templates, A and B, which simply alternate. It's basically the StrongLifts 5x5 and Starting Strength approach. All workouts have squats, and until now the deadlift was on workout A (so one week there'd be two deadlift sessions, the other week one). The deadlift is only done for one work set after warm-up. Thus far, the weight on the squats was increased every workout.

The plan was to turn Wednesday into a lighter back-off day for the squats once recovering started getting heavy, and at that point also do only one deadlift session per week. Since I'm feeling some lingering back stiffness from workout to workout, and progressing on the squats and deadlifts is getting increasingly difficult, now seems like a good time.

The question then is, which day would be best to put the deadlifts on? I can either put it on one of the heavy squat days (Monday/Friday) or on the lighter squat day (Wednesday). There's advantages and disadvantages to every choice.

- On Monday I'd have to do it after heavy squats, with my back and legs already tired. But the last workout will have been 3 days ago and it being the start of the work week I'll still be fresh.
- On Wednesday the squats will have been lighter and will interfere less with the deadlifts. But it's intended as a day to facilitate recovery and doing deadlifts on that day might defeat that purpose.
- On Friday there's the same problem as Monday: heavy squat + deadlift. But I tend to be enthusiastic cause the weekend is around the corner, the deadlift is the last exercise I do so I tend to have a "let's go mentality" and I'll get a whole weekend to recover from it, unlike Monday/Wednesday.

Is there any choice that's definitely better? My goal is to continue linear progression as long as possible and gradually move into the Texas Method programming style (where deadlifts are on the volume day, but I feel more inclined to put them on the intensity day).

Comment: Please see [this StartingStrength.com forum thread](http://startingstrength.com/resources/forum/programming/56325-deadlift-light-squat-day-weekly.html).

Comment: @CCCV Thanks for the reply. This week I did the first light squat day, but I haven't moved entirely over into the new phase yet so it also happened to the the A workout with deadlifts. It seemed to go well and my back feels fine today. On the third workout this week I'll have a better idea of whether it is enough to offset the recovery from the lighter squats, but my gut feeling says no. Still interested in hearing experiences or if anyone has a definite argument in favor of one specific day.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but what you described is close to the "Texas Method" style of training.  Basic gist is a moderately heavy squat/deadlift day on Monday, light squat day on Wednseday, then heavy squat and power clean day on Friday. So for example, on Monday it's a 5x5 squat session at 90% of 5RM, then a 1x5 deadlift session at 90% of 5RM. On Wednseday, you would do a 2x5 squat at 70% 5RM. Then on Friday, you attempt a new 5RM and do power cleans. Another example: http://www.powerliftingtowin.com/texas-method/

Comment: In that one they actually attempt 5 rep PRs on the same day, but the volume is way less overall.

Comment: @DeeV Indeed, the Texas method is what I'm eventually aiming for once linear progression gets stuck. And the idea to make Wednesday a light squat day comes from Starting Strength, which TM is a very natural follow-up for. So you could say I'm slowly transforming the program to Texas Method one exercise at a time, once it no longer progresses in a more simple way. TM places the deadlift on volume day (Monday) but I've seen at least one example in the SS forums where someone placed it on intensity day (Friday) instead. Maybe it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Tale as old as time!!! (Beauty and the best music playing).

Answer (score 0):

It is a compromise you have to make between lifting at maximal strength and being better at managing fatigue overall. If your CNS can manage it, then doing deadlifts with other high intensity movements should be fine for advanced lifters....not so much for beginners.